# Go Integrator with Nextiva sending invalid URL

Tags: url, voip

Has anyone ever used Go Integrator that Nextiva provides to send encoded urls? I have it sending a formatted variable to show the callers phone number, but any percent symbols get changed to an invalid code. Example:

`websiteaddress.com/search?query=fieldvalue%3A%%Call\Contact\DisplayTel%`

fieldvalue requires the colon (%3A) after to properly search the variable passed, and I added a % after %3A as without the extra % it would send the link but remove all the % symbols for the variable (Call\Contact\DisplayTel rather than the variable 916-555-1234).

For some reason when I send the URL it encodes the %3A as %03 instead, giving me a weird ASCII placeholder, showing this URL instead:

`websiteaddress.com/search?query=fieldvalue%03916-555-1234`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Go Integrator wants the actual characters and NOT pre-encoded URL's. Thus, the link should show:
`websiteaddress.com/search?query=fieldvalue:%Call\Contact\DisplayTel%`